# Python Regex to find a string with varible in double quotes

Tags: python, regex

A code in python using regex that can perform something like this

Input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){var d=document.domain;while (true){try{var A=window.parent.document.domain;break;}catch(e)
 {};d=d.replace(/.*?(?:\.|$)/,'');if (d.length==0) break;try{document.domain=d;}catch (e){break;}}})();
window.parent.OnUploadCompleted(0,"/userfiles/abc.txt","abc.txt", "") ;</script>
```

with abc.txt is a varible like `self.filename`

Output just: `/userfiles/abc.txt` without `abc.txt`

The problem is `userfiles` is a varible too.

Thanks./.

Comment: did u try anything?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh i try `'"/.*' + '/' + self.filename + '["]'` and it work but im not sure it still work with something like `/a/b/c/abc.txt`

Comment: @Emma its `/userfiles/abc.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1) What you want is always a txt file

2) The string is always a *path* which contains the character `/`

The following pattern should work:

```
import re

INPUT = """<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){var d=document.domain;while (true){try{var A=window.parent.document.domain;break;}catch(e)
 {};d=d.replace(/.*?(?:\.|$)/,'');if (d.length==0) break;try{document.domain=d;}catch (e){break;}}})();
window.parent.OnUploadCompleted(0,"/userfiles/abc.txt","abc.txt", "") ;</script>"""

get_path = re.search(r"\"([^\"]*\/[^\"]*txt)\"",INPUT).group(1)

print(get_path)
```

Output:

> /userfiles/abc.txt

[Link for reference](https://regex101.com/r/XqaKdP/1)

Answer (score 0):

This expression might likely work here:

```
OnUploadCompleted\([0-9]+\s*,\s*\"\/(.+?)\"
```

and our desired output is in this capturing group `(.+?)`.

[Please see the demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/pbwqJe/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"OnUploadCompleted\([0-9]+\s*,\s*\"\/(.+?)\""

test_str = ("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
    "(function(){var d=document.domain;while (true){try{var A=window.parent.document.domain;break;}catch(e)\n"
    " {};d=d.replace(/.*?(?:\\.|$)/,'');if (d.length==0) break;try{document.domain=d;}catch (e){break;}}})();\n"
    "window.parent.OnUploadCompleted(0,\"/userfiles/abc.txt\",\"abc.txt\", \"\") ;</script>")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Comment: I could be wrong but my understanding is OP wants the full path as the output (essentially the content within the first double quotes), what he/she doesn't need is _only_ the filename which is the content within the second pair of double quotes.